# C# SqlCommand textbox with spaces

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Windows Form Application

My `SqlCommand` works -- except, in the `Street` column (`Street VARCHAR(70)`), which gets the input from a textbox (`streetTextBox.Text`) throws an error if there is a space OR if its not a number. I can manually enter into database just fine and the command works as long as the street textbox is only a number with no spaces.

```
comm2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Addresses(Street, City, aState, Zip) values (" + streetTextBox.Text + ",'" + cityTextBox.Text + "','" + aStateTextBox.Text + "','" + zipTextBox.Text + "')", conn);

try
{
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Saved...");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Why will it not allow an actual street to be saved? (i.e. 555 Street Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is an open door for [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. 
You need to work with [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675101(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of concatenating strings into sql.

```
        comm2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Addresses(Street, City, aState, Zip) values (@Street, @City,@aState, @Zip)", conn);
        comm2.Parameters.Add("@Street", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = streetTextBox.Text;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cityTextBox.Text;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("@aState", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = aStateTextBox.Text;
        comm2.Parameters.Add("@Zip", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = zipTextBox.Text;

        try
        {
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved...");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because if it's varchar you need the single quotes around it, and you're missing them.

```
values ('" + streetTextBox.Text + "'
```

But please use [**Parameters**](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter), you prevent problems like this and SQL Injection

Comment: Why bother helping to fix the **wrong** way, when you can show the **right** way?

Comment: @ZoharPeled because I gave him the link showing him the right way to do it, he'll learn reading the tutorial better than copying and pasting the code without understanding it.

Comment: Giving the link is good, however showing the correct code is better. Links only answers are considered low quality posts in SO, and rightfully so.

Comment: It's not a link only answer, I gave him the answer, but advised him to use parameters. You just answered after and are trying to take the points, whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, prospector and ill be sure to use parameters.

Comment: @prospector You gave an answer on how to fix a **wrong** code, my answer is how to write a **correct** code. 15 points of reputation might seem like a lot when you have 1,400 rep, it's not that much when you have 16.5k. Trust me, it's not about the points. And when the correct way to write the code is just a line of text with a link, it's nothing but a link-only answer, even when you add the wrong code answer to it.

Comment: I gave my reasoning, so he could learn instead of copy and paste, I pointed it out, you just tried to "1 up me" for the rep. I don't care, enjoy it. Deny and justify it all you want, but the reality is you did it for the rep.

Comment: Whatever. think what you want, I know my reasons for posting what I believe to be a good answer. I will not downvote your answer as you did mine, even though I think it's not a good answer. and not because it will cost me 2 valuable reputation points... cheers.